# How do I send a command to a CLI that has been opened as a subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, subprocess

I am in need of some help. What I am trying to do is opening a subprocess with a python program and then make the subprocess execute specific commands at certain points of the program. Let me try to illustrate my problem with a very simple code snippet:

```
import subprocess
import time

#create a new terminal
cmd = ["gnome-terminal --window &"]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

#do something else
time.sleep(5)

#and now I want to execute a command in the new terminal
```

To begin with I'd be happy to see a simple command like `ls` or `ifconfig` work. Just something that puts some text in the new terminal to confirm that it works.

I had hoped that `Popen.communicate(input)` would do the trick, i.e something along the lines of `process.communicate("ls")`, but so far it seems like it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the pexpect module - it is designed for exactly that purpose, including looking for particular prompts and errors back from your subprocess.

A simple (cut-down) example from a script I wrote. It uses an ssh session to log in and run a script on a server.

```
import pexpect

server = "server.home" # normally passed as arguments
display = 1            # normally passed as arguments

ssh = pexpect.spawn("ssh", ["{0}".format(server), "~/vnc.py", "{0}".format(display)])
try:
    index = ssh.expect("^.*password:")
except:
    print "Have not received password prompt from {host} - server down or ssh not enabled".format(host=server)
    sys.exit(1)

if index == 0:   
    ssh.sendline( password )
else:
    print "Unable to communicate with server"
```

Very useful especially if you have complex interactions.

BTW the full script is a homebrew set of scripts that allow me to start a VNC server on my remote server (running as a print server), and then log a vnc viewer onto the VNC server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that works on windows. Maybe it helps ...

Popen.communicate is cosing the process and returns stdout in it's result. I can call it only once. If I want to send multiple commands I need to put them in a string and add \n after each.

```
## @ingroup cliFunc
#  @brief run a commandline inside a shell
#
#  run a command in a console and return it's output
#
#  @param command   :[\b string] commandline to execute
#  @param tempDir   :[\b string][\em optional] directory to run the command
#  @return           [\b string] a string with the output
def runCommandStdOut(command, tempDir = None):
    # redirect standard output (including the print statement)
    # creationflags for windows
    # CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
    p = sp.Popen("cmd.exe /X/D/F:ON", stdin=sp.PIPE,
                    stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, creationflags=0x08000000)
    flag = "(@@@@@@}"
    cmand = "PROMT"+flag+'\n'

    if tempDir:
    cmand +=  "cd " + tempDir +"\n"


    cmand += command
    return p.communicate(cmand+"\n")[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html I am supposed to use 'communicate' instead of 'stdin', or? 

_Warning

Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process._

Comment: Yes, I've updated my example. Works as well and avoids the blocking mentioned in documentation.

Comment: I suggest adding \n after "ls".